# Is there a method to smoothen polygons and force all angles to be 90 degrees?

Tags: pandas, geometry, gis, geospatial, geopandas

Is there a way to smoothen jagged polygons and get nice 90 degree angles like in the image below? Any algorithms or methods would be useful!

I've tried geopandas' `.simplify()` function, which uses the  Douglas-Peucker algorithm, but the results aren't as smooth and the quality of results varies depending on the shape of the polygon.

Are there any existing algorithms or approaches to achieve this?

[image]

[Image Source here.](https://github.com/microsoft/AustraliaBuildingFootprints?fbclid=IwAR0FS7JEHLHxiRuxwCcEXWlSrlsnDxvdfAIj7o9K0yYA5Ol2llG21Vj16FA)

Comment: There is certainly nothing built-in which would do this. This is a complex operation. Also, notice that the example above is done on raster data.

Comment: You might have better luck on gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [probabilistic hough transform](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html#probabilistic-hough-transform)

Find line segments on binary image(left), then re-create polygon using intersection points.